# Slow performance for Node.js running on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I am running a very simple RESTful API on AWS using Node.js. The API takes a request in the form of '/rest/users/jdoe' and returns the following (it's all done in memory, no database involved):

```
{
    username: 'jdoe',
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
}
```

The performance of this API on Node.js + AWS is horrible compared to the local network - only 9 requests/sec vs. 2,214 requests/sec on a local network. AWS is running a m1.medium instance whereas the local Node server is a desktop machine with an Intel i7-950 processor. Trying to figure out why such a huge difference in performance.

Benchmarks using Apache Bench are as follows:

**Local Network**

10,000 requests with concurrency of 100/group

```
> ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://192.168.1.100:8080/rest/users/jdoe

Document Path:          /rest/users/jdoe
Document Length:        70 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   4.516 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      2350000 bytes
HTML transferred:       700000 bytes
Requests per second:    2214.22 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       45.163 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.452 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          508.15 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.4      0       2
Processing:    28   45   7.2     44      74
Waiting:       22   43   7.5     42      74
Total:         28   45   7.2     44      74

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     44
  66%     46
  75%     49
  80%     51
  90%     54
  95%     59
  98%     65
  99%     67
 100%     74 (longest request)
```

**AWS**

1,000 requests with concurrency of 100/group
(10,000 requests would have taken too long)

```
C:\apps\apache-2.2.21\bin>ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://54.200.x.xxx:8080/rest/users/jdoe
Document Path:          /rest/users/jdoe
Document Length:        70 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   105.693 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      235000 bytes
HTML transferred:       70000 bytes
Requests per second:    9.46 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       10569.305 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       105.693 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2.17 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       98  105   3.8    106     122
Processing:   103 9934 1844.8  10434   10633
Waiting:      103 5252 3026.5   5253   10606
Total:        204 10040 1844.9  10540   10736

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  10540
  66%  10564
  75%  10588
  80%  10596
  90%  10659
  95%  10691
  98%  10710
  99%  10726
 100%  10736 (longest request)
```

Questions:

- Connect time for AWS is 105 ms (avg) compared to 0 ms on local network. I assume that this is because it takes a lot more time to open a socket to AWS then to a server on a local network. Is there anything to be done here for better performance under load assuming requests are coming in from multiple machines across the globe.
- More serious is the server processing time - 45 ms for local server compared to 9.9 seconds for AWS! I can't figure out what's going on in here. The server is only pressing 9.46 requests/sec. which is peanuts!

Any insight into these issues much appreciated. I am nervous about putting a serious application on Node+AWS if it can't perform super fast on such a simple application.

For reference here's my server code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/rest/users/:id', function(req, res) {
    var user = {
        username: req.params.id,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    };
    res.json(user);
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Listening on port 8080');
```

**Edit**

*Single request sent in isolation (-n 1 -c 1)*

```
Requests per second:    4.67 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       214.013 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       214.013 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1.07 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      104  104   0.0    104     104
Processing:   110  110   0.0    110     110
Waiting:      110  110   0.0    110     110
Total:        214  214   0.0    214     214
```

*10 request all sent concurrently (-n 10 -c 10)*

```
Requests per second:    8.81 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1135.066 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       113.507 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2.02 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       98  103   3.4    102     110
Processing:   102  477 296.0    520     928
Waiting:      102  477 295.9    520     928
Total:        205  580 295.6    621    1033
```

*Results using wrk*

As suggested by Andrey Sidorov. The results are MUCH better - 2821 requests per second:

```
Running 30s test @ http://54.200.x.xxx:8080/rest/users/jdoe
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   137.04ms   48.12ms   2.66s    98.89%
    Req/Sec   238.11     27.97   303.00     88.91%
  84659 requests in 30.01s, 19.38MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 53
Requests/sec:   2821.41
Transfer/sec:    661.27KB
```

So it certainly looks like the culprit is ApacheBench! Unbelievable!

Comment: Breaking this up into smaller pieces, the first question that jumps out is, what does a single request sent in isolation look like as far as response time?  Is it reasonable?  Second, while benchmarking, are you maxing the CPU on the AWS machine? Is there a lower concurrency breakpoint where the responsiveness levels out?

Comment: I added the numbers for single request and 10 concurrent requests (see edits in the question). Response times are still pretty high: 214 ms and 580ms (4.67 requests/sec and 8.81 requests/sec). CPU on AWS is practically idle (1.25%).

Comment: You'll want to benchmark from within AWS to get a better apples-to-apples answer, because I've confirmed what I suspected (in my own tests) that "connect" can never be less than the approximate ping time from 'ab' to the server, and "total" can never be less than 2 x ping... it's timing the *entire* connection from open to close; so while you do appear to have something worth investigating, I suspect you aren't going to see numbers that are especially meaningful or really comparable to the local test, until you try a "local" test initiated from within the same EC2 availability zone.

Comment: But benchmarking from within AWS is not realistic. I would like to see a respectable throughput when hit from outside, even if it is much less that a "local" test. But ab is showing dismal. See my results using wrk as suggested by Andrey. It looks like wrk is able to produce a much better load.

Comment: No, it isn't realistic at all... however, benchmarking your local system locally is equally unrealistic.  My only point was that to be able to compare the two results, they need to be generated in comparable environments.  If you had similarly benchmarked your local machine from a distant location with ab, you would have presumably also seen poor results, which would confirm that ab is somehow providing less-than-helpful numbers.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for all your input. I am sure this entire discussion is going to be very useful for others in the same situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably ab issue (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216267/ab-program-freezes-after-lots-of-requests-why)). There is nothing wrong in your server code. I suggest to try to benchmark using [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) load testing tool. Your example on my t1.micro:

```
wrk git:master ❯ ./wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s http://some-amazon-hostname.com/rest/users/10                                                                                                                                                                                          ✭
Running 30s test @ http://some-amazon-hostname.com/rest/users/10
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   333.42ms  322.01ms   3.20s    91.33%
    Req/Sec   135.02     59.20   283.00     65.32%
  48965 requests in 30.00s, 11.95MB read
Requests/sec:   1631.98
Transfer/sec:    407.99KB
```

Comment: Certainly looks like the culprit is ApacheBench! I am getting 2821 requests/second using wrk! Thank you. BTW have you compared wrk with JMeter. Any opinions?

Comment: never used JMeter. Consider siege, httperf and wrk in addition to ab, and wrk is probably the best and most actively developed tool.

Comment: Will look into these tools. Thanks again for all your insight.