# http.Response.Body copying leads to large memory usage increase

Tags: go

So I'm trying to get the response body out of http.Response, to do some manipulation, and then set it back. This is my first attempt at getting it out without draining the http.Response:

```
bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    // err
} else {
    cachedBody := string(bodyBytes)

    // Restore the io.ReadCloser to its original state
    // This is causing huge increases in memory usage.
    resp.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))
}
```

If I send 500 requests through, with a 1mb response size (a large piece of JSON, but it could be any format, not only JSON), the server memory usage goes up to ~400mb, and doesn't come back down. Is this normal? Is there something wrong with the above code? Am I missing something to release the memory?

defer resp.Body.Close() has no effect.

Thanks!

---

Edit 1

Here's a gist with a simple version of the proxy, including the suggested close call. If the server at localhost:3000 (where it's proxying to) returns a large response, memory usage will quickly increase. In my case, I'm returning a 1mb json file, and sending 500 requests through the go proxy increases memory usage to around 400mb.

The go proxy:
https://gist.github.com/marbemac/300c4c376171cbd27cc3

A simple node server that returns a file in the same directory called large_response.json.
https://gist.github.com/marbemac/55aaa78f5858484d33f6

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080642/memory-leak-in-go-http-standard-library  Try `go prof`

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, thanks for linking, but I don't think that's it. This is a sudden and dramatic increase (from 6mb starting state to 400mb in a couple seconds, sending those 500 requests against it). I feel like there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Confused about what you're trying to do here. Of course `defer resp.Body.Close()` has no effect, you're making it a `ioutil.NopCloser`. Read it, close it before making `Close()` a no-op, and then set it, what happens?

Comment: Maybe you need to `resp.Body.Close()` after `bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`?

Comment: First: You say it results in a "huge increases in memory usage": How do you measure this memory usage? Second: Why does this memoryusage bother you? (Maybe it's 'unproblematic' memory, e.g. large but allocated in one step, containing no pointers.) Third: In your gist: Why do you read the body at all in your RoundTrip? Is the "manipulation"-part missing? Are you sure the memory consumption is not triggered in your manipulation code (e.g. `cachedBody := string(bodyBytes)` probably makes a copy? Maybe a io.TeeReader could help reading the body for manipulation while re-sending it.

Comment: @volker I'm simply looking at the process in activity monitor. Unscientific, I know, but it jumps from 1mb -> 400mb. It bothers me because I don't quite understand what's happening here, and if I increase the # of requests sent against it to say, 2000, memory goes up to ~700mb. The memory issues are present in the code linked in the gist, so it has nothing to do with my manipulation code (unfortunately, would be easier for me to find and fix). The manipulation code isn't included because it's noise, and complicates the example.

Comment: I understand. Which type of memory "goes up"? Most probably it just does not matter at all because this is virtual memory. Maybe you could measure allocations via `go test -benchmem` and an appropriate benchmark to see if you allocate and do a real memory profile. "Memory" as shown by top et al. goes up and is not released and this is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

The Body must be closed after use. Refer to [this](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response)

Notice that the `defer resp.Body.Close()` is invoked after you reassign the `resp.Body` with new value.

Answer (score 2):

[`ioutil.NopCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser) makes `Close()` do nothing. You're never actually closing it if you defer the close. Close right after reading instead.

```
bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    // err
} 
resp.Body.Close()
cachedBody := string(bodyBytes)
// Close() does nothing after this
resp.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))
```

Also in Go you're typically able to ignore that `else` because you should probably be returning the error or handling it in the `if` above it.

Things like this are times when it would be nice to have a [`sync.Pool`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool) as well, since you keep recycling huge buffers, check how it is used in the `net/http` package for an example.

Comment: I isolated everything to the gist linked in my edit. I'm calling close, but still seeing memory jump from ~1mb to 400mb in just a couple of seconds. If you have time time, let me know if you see the same result on your machine. Thanks!

Comment: If your error isn't `nil` you're not closing. Are you sure your error is `nil`? You're also not doing anything with the first `err`. You have to actually do something with errors..

Comment: Yes I forgot to handle the err, but it's not getting triggered. I just re-ran on my computer with a print statement in there to check.