# Spark 3.1.3 with Hive dynamic partitions fails while driver moves the staged files

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

Running on Dataproc 2.0/1.3/1.4, we use INSERT INTO OVERWRITE command to insert new (time) partitions into existing Hive tables. But we see too many failures coming from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.replaceFiles, that is where the driver moves the successful files from staging to final directory.

For some reason, the underlying FS implementation - GoogleCloudStorageImpl in this case - fails to move at least one file and the exception is propagated all the way through. We see many different failures - from hadoop.FileSystem.mkdirs, rename, etc., all coming from Hive.replaceFiles().
I guess FS failures are expected, but nowhere in org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadDynamicPartitions there is try/catch/retry mechanism.

Is it expected that the FS implementation do it? 
Because the GCS connector does not seem to do that :)

We ended up patching and rebuilding hive-exec jar as an immediate mitigation (try/catch/retry), while our platform teams are reaching out to GCP support.

I know this is more of a Hive issue rather than Spark, but still I wonder if anybody has encountered this issue, or similar?

---

Edit:

This is a stack trace of a failed application. In this case the failed operation was mkdirs(). Please note, hive-exec was slightly modified so line numbers are not aligned with the public source code.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Cannot assign requested address (connect failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptSocket.connect(AbstractConscryptSocket.java:155)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.&lt;init&gt;(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:519)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:536)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.directUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:332)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:306)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:528)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.createEmptyObject(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:507)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.createEmptyObject(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:535)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:478)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.mkdirs(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:446)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.mkdirs(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:2216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.lambda$null$5(Hive.java:2786)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.thrift.TException: Load dynamic partitions failed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadDynamicPartitions(Hive.java:1660)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v1_2.loadDynamicPartitions(HiveShim.scala:966)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:773)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:209)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.loadDynamicPartitions(HiveClientImpl.scala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:883)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        ... 40 more
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: @DagangWei added

Comment: The root cause was `Cannot assign requested address`,  seems it ran out of local ephemeral ports. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800692/multiple-http-requests-gives-cant-assign-requested-address-unless-sped-up

Comment: Are you running many concurrent jobs?

Comment: Do you mean from inside the same application/cluster? No, BUT hive-exec was modified to use concurrent threads to move the files. In some cases, hundreds or even thousands of threads. Thank you very much for the link, seems very relevant.

Comment: I see, it is caused by high concurrent http connections, you might want to limit the concurrenency level.

Comment: The max port number is an OS level limitation, so it doesn't matter whether it is multiple theads within a single app process, or multiple app processes.